# Get all entries vom Firebase Database in Ionic

Tags: javascript, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

I tried to get all entries from my Firebase database structure in Ionic.

Can someone please help me?

I tried it this way, but I does not work.

```
    firebase.database().ref("Inserate/").get().then((res) => {
      if (res.exists()) {
        res.forEach(data => {
          var obj = data.val();
          console.log(obj.city);
        });
      }
    });
```

This is my realtime database structure in firebase:

```
- Inserate
  - User ID 1
    - Unique Key ID 1
      - city
      - country
      - state
      - ...
    - Unique Key ID 2
      - city
      - country
      - state
      - ...
 - User ID 2
    - Unique Key ID 3
      - city
      - country
      - state
      - ...
    - Unique Key ID 4
      - city
      - country
      - state
      - ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have two nested dynamic levels under `Inserate`, first the level for the users, and then for each user a list of nodes.

Your code only handles the first dynamic level, so your `data.val()` contains the information user for a user. And a user doesn't have a `city` property, which explains why it doesn't show that.

To fix this, you'll need to have two nested loops:

```
firebase.database().ref("Inserate/").get().then((res) => {
  if (res.exists()) {
    res.forEach(user => {
      user.forEach(data => {
        var obj = data.val();
        console.log(obj.city);
      });
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining and the fast solution! It works!